# How to make a Call in Android Studio using Twilio android sdk?

Tags: android-studio, twilio

I am trying to integrate twilio android SDK in android Studio for implementing the outgoing call.Its Working fine in Eclipse but after I added the TwilioClientService in manifest.xml file, App is crashing in Android Studio so that i could not able to connect the call.Could you please any one tell the solution for this.

This is the Error I got,

1. STACK_TRACE=java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
   "/data/app/com.iw.infowave-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64,
   /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libtwilio-native.so" at
   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366) at
   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988) at
   com.twilio.client.impl.useragent.UserAgent.(UserAgent.java:16)
   at
   com.twilio.client.impl.CallControlManager.initialize(CallControlManager.java:189)
   at
   com.twilio.client.impl.CallControlManager.getInstance(CallControlManager.java:131)
   at
   com.twilio.client.impl.TwilioClientServiceImpl.initialize(TwilioClientServiceImpl.java:169)
   at
   com.twilio.client.TwilioClientService.onCreate(TwilioClientService.java:50)
   at
   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2761)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:151)
   at
   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1386)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at
   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) at
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCa`enter code
   here`ller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) at
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you haven't imported the library into your project.

See where it says:

> couldn't find "libtwilio-native.so" at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366) at

You need to have the twilioclient-android.jar in your libs folder and have it properly referenced.

If you want to see how to do that, the easiest way is to follow the docs [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android) or have a look at this sample project I put together [here](https://github.com/mplacona/android-twilio-client).

**UPDATE**
Also, as a side-note, you have to absolutely make sure the .so files are accessible by your project. If you're using Gradle, all you need to do is create a new folder under src/main called `jniLibs` and add all the contents of the lib folder there. This will make sure all the native SDK files are correctly referenced. You can see that on the sample project i posted earlier

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi I have added that jar file even-though it is coming like that.Actually i added one service in Android manifest file. it is TwilioClientService after i added that only i got this issue.

Comment: Have you had a look at the sample project I linked? Worth comparing what's missing in yours. I don't know much about your project, so hard to diagnose the issue.

Comment: yes In the same way I too did Which they mentioned in that link

Comment: No, I mean the sample project I put together. Have you tried running that one?

Comment: @Shine I've posted an update that might be useful to you

Comment: @Shine was this helpful? Can you mark it as answered if you solved your problem?